# Не пойму как с Регулярными выражениями заменить часть строки в txt файле

Tags: python

Есть файл в формате txt (userbouquet.IPTV.tv) —- правлю его в Notepad++. 
В этом файле есть строки которые нужно заменить, чтобы EPG заработало. 
В этой строке:

```
#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD —— нужно заменить эту часть текста 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0  в начале, на 4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0.
```

1. Строку ищем по названию канала ПЛАНЕТА HD или другое название.
2. Текст в середине всегда разный `http%3a//106.171.58.141%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:`

Строк много только разные каналы. Вручную править очень не удобно. Как это сделать - Регулярными выражениями или Python?
Так было:

```
#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD
```

Так должно быть после замены:

```
4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD
```

Comment: Добавьте пример исходной строки (без комментариев) и пример строки, которую хотите получить в результате.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать регулярными выражениями, например так:

```
import re
src=r"#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD"
res = re.sub(r"4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:", "4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0:", src)
print(res)
```

> `#SERVICE 4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD`

С другой стороны, зачем вам регулярки, если искомая строка и строка замены всегда одни и те же? Проще воспользоваться методом replace:

```
src=r"#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD"
res = src.replace("4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:", "4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0:")
print(res)
```

Так же получим:

> `#SERVICE 4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0:http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224:ПЛАНЕТА HD`

Comment: http%3a//106.121.58.171%3a81/udp/239.54.7.170%3a1224 ---     1. этот фрагмент в поиске будет всегда разный. 2 Эти фрагменты строки всегда будут повторяться: Первый -- #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0: и  второй :ПЛАНЕТА HD

Comment: Не важно, что фрагмент с `http` будет разным - он у вас остается в результате таким же, как был в исходной строке. у вас меняется постоянно только одна и та же строка на одну и ту же другую строку в промежутке между `SERVICE` и `http:`. Или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Всё правильно. в промежутке между SERVICE и http:. --- этот фрагмент я должен заменить.

Comment: @Александр тогда мой код вам подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Можно без применения регулярок переписать.

```
before = "4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0"
after = "4097:0:1:5A3C:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0"
file_path = "userbouquet.IPTV.tv"

with open(file_path, "r") as old_file:
    res = str()
    for line in old_file.readlines():
        res += line.replace(before, after)
    with open(file_path, "w") as new_file:
        new_file.write(res)
```

Путь к файлу в переменной file_path измените на нужный, если скрипт запускаете не из папки с файлом.

Comment: Спасибо Алексей М. А как в Ваш код добавить чтобы строки замены брались последовательно из файла txt с содержимым:  4097:0:1:908A:25:FD:1680000:0:0:0
Охотник и Рыболов HD
4097:0:1:5A46:17:FD:1680000:0:0:0
Охотник и Рыболов
4097:0:1:138D:5:FD:1680000:0:0:0
ТЕХНО 24
4097:0:1:7D3:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0